# Maven build not exporting dependent library's for packaging type jar

Tags: java, maven

I need to create a runnable jar file that will be operated in Batch mode.
During development I need to use following api/frameworks apache-poi,hibernate,Spring etc.

So,I prefer to go with maven:

Please find below my maven file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
          <version>3.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
    <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <archive>
                      <manifest>
                          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <mainClass>fully.qualified.classpath.Main</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                       <manifestEntries>
                         <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                      </manifestEntries>
                   </archive>
              </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
 </project>
```

I am running the maven build from eclipse as `clean package`.
Build completes successfully.But in the generated jar all the dependent jar
is not present [spring/hibernate/poi] etc.

We need to run this jar as `java -jar jarname` from command prompt/console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies

Spring framework can do similar thing for you. [Generate sample project](https://start.spring.io/) and check its `pom` file.

Comment: I cannot go with spring boot since my application is kind of a cron job application.It will be triggered by a third party app just like a batch job

Comment: Have you seen [scheduling](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) feature?

Comment: I know that.but it is not based on time exactly.it will be triggred based on some third party event

Answer (score 0):

`maven-jar-plugin` provides the capability to build jars without dependencies.
To create jar with all it's dependencies you can use `maven-assembly-plugin` or `maven-shade-plugin`. Below is `maven-assembly-plugin` configuration in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                            fully.qualified.classpath.Main
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

More information: [executable-jar-with-maven](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven)

Comment: maven-shade-plugin solve the issue.but while running using java -jar option it gives a separate exception as follows::

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 651; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out inside your pom.xml file:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                    <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```